# What's the best way to code an input tag with certain locked characters?

Tags: javascript, html

## Introduction

I would like to make an input of a fixed length that you can only fill some of the characters, for instance let's say I have `__llo w_rld!` and i want the user to fill in the gaps, but not allow to modify the prefilled characters.

## Ideas

I thought of using an input tag for each character and mark as disabled the prefilled ones, here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input size="1"></input>
  <input size="1"></input>
  <input size="1" value="l" disabled></input>
  <input size="1" value="l" disabled></input>
  <input size="1" value="o" disabled></input>
  &ensp;
  <input size="1" value="w" disabled></input>
  <input size="1"></input>
  <input size="1" value="r" disabled></input>
  <input size="1" value="l" disabled></input>
  <input size="1" value="d" disabled></input>
  <input size="1" value="!" disabled></input>
</body>
</html>
```

However this approach doesn't allow the user to keep typing characters and jump from one input to the next one.

Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `required` and `querySelector(':invalid')` seems to work pretty well.

By the way, it's not valid html to end `<input>` tags.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.addEventListener("input", ev => {
  container.querySelector("input:invalid")?.focus();
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input required maxlength="1">
  <input required maxlength="1">
  <input value="l" disabled>
  <input value="l" disabled>
  <input value="o" disabled>
  &ensp;
  <input value="w" disabled>
  <input required maxlength="1">
  <input value="r" disabled>
  <input value="l" disabled>
  <input value="d" disabled>
  <input value="!" disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: Technically you are supposed to close input tags, but they are supposed to be self closed as `<input />` Since they have to be void tags, most browsers are just coded not to care.

Comment: @Andrew:  That's a common misconception.  But for void tags, the trailing slash is completely optional and has no meaning.  Here are [some examples](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2) from WHATWG omitting the slash.  On that page, check out 13.1.2.1.6.  "Then, if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/). This character has no effect on void elements, but on foreign elements it marks the start tag as self-closing."

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, the one character long text boxes are a fallback not what you actually want? If so you can use a regex to reject anything that doesn't match. To do so you use a `.` for every character you are leaving blank and the character for each one you want to be fixed. The regex for your hello world example is `/..llo w.rld!/` and you revert the field value to the last version that passed this test every time it fails. Technically they can edit those characters, but the code will change them back immediately after:

```js
let lastValue = '__llo w_rld!';
let currentValue = '__llo w_rld!';
const regex = new RegExp('..llo w.rld!');
testTextID.value = lastValue;
    const strLength = 12;

function overwriteTestText(e){
    let caretpos = testTextID.selectionStart;
    currentValue = testTextID.value;
    if (currentValue.length == strLength + 1){
        currentValue = removeCharacter(currentValue, caretpos);
    }

    testText(e, false);
   
    //selecting 0 characters long puts the caret at that position.
    testTextID.setSelectionRange(caretpos, caretpos);
}

function testText(e, readInput = true){
    if(readInput) {
        currentValue = testTextID.value;
    }

    if (regex.test(currentValue) && currentValue.length == strLength) {
        lastValue = currentValue;
    }

    testTextID.value = lastValue;
}

function removeCharacter(str, pos) {
    return str.slice(0,pos) + str.slice(pos+1);
}
```

```html
  <input id="testTextID" onkeyup="overwriteTestText()"  onblur="testText()" />
```

Comment: If you use an entry mechanism that doesn't fire keyup, this doesn't do anything.  And even if you do, there doesn't seem to be a way to clear mistaken entries.

Comment: @recursive fair on the key up part, splitting the function and adding onblur handling. As far as clearing mistaken entries, either the mistake fits the regex pattern, and you can go back and overwrite your mistake with another entry, or it breaks the pattern and the code rejects the mistake.

Comment: It's not so obvious how you're supposed to overwrite your mistaken entry.  I tried to select the mistake, and type the correct character, but that just reverts to the old bad value.

Comment: @recursive fixed to allow select and overwrite manually